# Order Email not showing product list - Magento 2.4.3-p2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

After upgrading Magento to 2.4.3-p3 version all the order emails are not showing the items in the emails.

Does anyone have come across such an issue and had a solution?

I can see https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Order-Email-not-showing-itemized-list-Magento-2-3-4/td-p/432836 but that's for Magento2.3.4 version and solutions on that tread does not help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Check the email templates, find and replace:

> {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}

to

> {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}

ie. The variable `order` is changed to `order_id`

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

The variable **order** is changed to **order_id** ***[ Magento Version 2.4.x ]***

On the email templates!!

***Find :***

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

***Replace With:***

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}
```